# How to generate an access trail report in a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to generate a report based in three different tables which stores a kind of trail of a system process. The Source_Base table stores her process try, and the successful or fail result of the last robot called. The Source_Robot table stores a trail of each robot called. Finally, if an exception was occurred in some robot, this will stored on the Robot_Exception table.

Here down I'll try to show these tables:

```
Source_Base (Showing only a portion of the real data)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
AccesID     | OwnerAccessID | StartTime     | EndTime       | Success 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1248683283  |  0            | 09:10:23.237  | 09:10:26.727  | 0
1248683284  |  10013553     | 09:10:23.233  | 09:12:05.703  | 1
1248683285  |  0            | 14:24:32.037  | 14:24:39.313  | 0
1248683286  |  10013555     | 14:24:32.030  | 14:25:42.387  | 1
1248683287  |  0            | 14:44:47.747  | 14:44:50.973  | 1
1248683288  |  1248683287   | 14:44:47.747  | 14:44:51.697  | 1


Source_Robot 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AccesID     | OwnerAccessID | RobotID | StartTime    | EndTime      |   Success 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10013551    |   1248683283  | 11      | 09:10:27.587 | 09:11:17.605 |   0
10013552    |   10013551    | 12      | 09:11:18.186 | 09:11:18.219 |   0
10013553    |   10013552    | 13      | 09:11:18.323 | 09:12:05.003 |   1
10013554    |   1248683285  | 15      | 14:24:41.763 | 14:25:36.313 |   0
10013555    |   10013554    | 14      | 14:25:37.393 | 14:25:39.967 |   1


Robot_Exception
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
ExceptionID | OwnerAccessID | RobotID   | StartTime     | EndTime                   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
999993      |   10013554    |   15      | 14:24:41.763  | 14:25:36.313  
999992      |   10013552    |   12      | 09:11:18.189  | 09:11:18.217  
999991      |   10013551    |   11      | 09:10:27.593  | 09:11:17.603
```

And now I wish to have some report like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AccesID     |   OwnerAccessID   |   RobotID     | Success | Exception | Duration
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1248683283  |   0               |   NULL        | 0       | NULL      | (datediff)
10013551    |   1248683283      |   11          | 0       | 999991    | (datediff)
10013552    |   10013551        |   12          | 0       | 999992    | (datediff)
10013553    |   10013552        |   13          | 1       | NULL      | (datediff)
1248683284  |   10013553        |   NULL        | 1       | NULL      | (datediff)
1248683285  |   0               |   NULL        | 0       | NULL      | (datediff)
10013554    |   1248683285      |   15          | 0       | 999993    | (datediff)
10013555    |   10013554        |   14          | 1       | NULL      | (datediff)
1248683286  |   10013555        |   NULL        | 1       | NULL      | (datediff)
1248683288  |   1248683287      |   NULL        | 1       | NULL      | (datediff)
1248683287  |   0               |   NULL        | 1       | NULL      | (datediff)
```

I try to solve the problem with CTE but, some values are not appearing on the report, I'm sure that my last query is wrong. Or using the CTE is not the right way.

```
WITH Source_Base_CTE (AccesID, OwnerAccessID, RobotID, StartTime, EndTime, Duration, Success)
AS
(SELECT 
        AccesID,
        OwnerAccessID,
        0 as RobotID,
        StartTime,
        EndTime,
        datediff (second, StartTime, EndTime) as Duration,
        Success
    FROM 
        Source_Base 
    ),
Source_Robot_CTE (AccesID, OwnerAccessID, RobotID, StartTime, EndTime, Duration, Success)
AS
(SELECT 
        AccesID,
        OwnerAccessID,
        RobotID,
        StartTime,
        EndTime,
        datediff (second, StartTime, EndTime) as Duration,
        Success
    FROM 
        Source_Robot 
    )
SELECT * FROM Source_Base_CTE WHERE StartTime > '00:00:00.00'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Source_Robot_CTE WHERE StartTime > '00:00:00.00' AND OwnerAccessID in (SELECT AccesID FROM Source_Base_CTE) 
ORDER BY StartTime ASC
```

Result:

```
AccesID     OwnerAccessID   RobotID StartTime       EndTime         Duration    Success

1248683284  10013551        0       09:10:23.233    09:12:05.703    102         1
1248683283  0               0       09:10:23.237    09:10:26.727    3           0
10013551    1248683283      12      09:10:27.587    09:11:17.603    50          0
1248683286  10013554        0       14:24:32.030    14:25:42.387    70          1
1248683285  0               0       14:24:32.037    14:24:39.313    7           0
10013553    1248683285      15      14:24:41.763    14:25:36.313    55          0
1248683288  1248683287      0       14:44:47.747    14:44:51.697    4           1
1248683287  0               0       14:44:47.747    14:44:50.973    3           1
1248683289  0               0       16:23:35.930    16:23:38.857    3           0
1248683290  10013557        0       16:23:35.930    16:24:34.197    59          1
10013555    1248683289      12      16:23:39.727    16:24:17.860    38          0
```

If anyone can give me a way I'll appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iDtVPvCnXV6E92CzyWNjWK/0

Press run there to see the result of 11 rows.

SQL:

```
with source as (
  select AccesID, OwnerAccessID, null RobotID, StartTime, EndTime, Success from Source_Base union
  select AccesID, OwnerAccessID,      RobotID, StartTime, EndTime, Success from Source_Robot
)
select AccesID,OwnerAccessID, RobotID, Success,
  (select ExceptionID from Robot_Exception e where e.OwnerAccessID=source.AccesID) Exception,
  round(extract(epoch from EndTime)-extract(epoch from StartTime)) duration,
  starttime
from source
order by StartTime;
```

With your sample tables:

```
create table source_base ( accesid numeric, owneraccessid numeric, starttime timestamp, endtime timestamp, success numeric );
insert into source_base values 
(1248683283, 0,          '2019-04-10 09:10:23.237', '2019-04-10 09:10:26.727', 0),
(1248683284, 10013553,   '2019-04-10 09:10:23.233', '2019-04-10 09:12:05.703', 1),
(1248683285, 0,          '2019-04-10 14:24:32.037', '2019-04-10 14:24:39.313', 0),
(1248683286, 10013555,   '2019-04-10 14:24:32.030', '2019-04-10 14:25:42.387', 1),
(1248683287, 0,          '2019-04-10 14:44:47.747', '2019-04-10 14:44:50.973', 1),
(1248683288, 1248683287, '2019-04-10 14:44:47.747', '2019-04-10 14:44:51.697', 1);

create table source_robot ( accesid numeric, owneraccessid numeric, robotid numeric, starttime timestamp, endtime timestamp, success numeric );
insert into source_robot values
(10013551, 1248683283, 11, '2019-04-10 09:10:27.587', '2019-04-10 09:11:17.605', 0),
(10013552, 10013551,   12, '2019-04-10 09:11:18.186', '2019-04-10 09:11:18.219', 0),
(10013553, 10013552,   13, '2019-04-10 09:11:18.323', '2019-04-10 09:12:05.003', 1),
(10013554, 1248683285, 15, '2019-04-10 14:24:41.763', '2019-04-10 14:25:36.313', 0),
(10013555, 10013554,   14, '2019-04-10 14:25:37.393', '2019-04-10 14:25:39.967', 1);

create table robot_exception (exceptionid numeric, owneraccessid numeric, robotid numeric, starttime timestamp, endtime timestamp);
insert into robot_exception values
(999993, 10013554, 15, '2019-04-10 14:24:41.763', '2019-04-10 14:25:36.313'),
(999992, 10013552, 12, '2019-04-10 09:11:18.189', '2019-04-10 09:11:18.217'),
(999991, 10013551, 11, '2019-04-10 09:10:27.593', '2019-04-10 09:11:17.603');
```

Comment: I'm really thank for your time in a good answer, but now I'm getting this error "Subquery returned more than 1 value ...". Notice that both table (Base and Robot) are huge, im my sample I just give a portion of data.

Comment: I've made a little change to the answer for get the thing working on the subquery `select ExceptionID from Robot_Exception e where e.OwnerAccessID=source.AccesID`